# WSO2 ESB payload from property

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to create a payload from a property content:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>$1</format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Response')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

WSO2 ESB is not accepting this as a valid payload format. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you use PayloadFactory for this? You can use Enrich mediator and replace the envelope (or body) with the property, if the property is of type OMElement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Payload Factory for this. It requires a wrapping XML tag like this.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format><Root>$1</Root></format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Response')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

But you can do what you want with [Enrich mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Enrich+Mediator).

```
<enrich>
   <source clone="false" type="property" property="ORIGINAL_PAYLOAD"/>
   <target action="replace" type="body"/>
</enrich>
```

[Here](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2015/08/wso2-esb-replacing-message-body-by.html) is a similar sample.

Answer (score 0):

May be because of the type of the 'Response' Clovis. 
I'm using this and found no problem.

```
<property description="requestBk" expression="json-eval($.)" name="requestBk" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>$1</format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:requestBk"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

One other tip. Use `$ctx:` instead of `get-property` method for a better performance. Because `get-property` looks in the `registry` also.

And yes! as Bhathiya and Maria suggested you can use the `Enrich mediator` also as mentioned below.
Copy the original payload to a property using the `Enrich mediator`.

```
<enrich>
  <source clone="false" type="body"/>
  <target action="replace" type="property" property="ORGINAL_PAYLOAD"/>
</enrich>
```

Then whenever you need the original payload, you replace the message body with this property value using the `Enrich mediator` as follows:

```
<enrich>
  <source clone="false" type="property" property="ORIGINAL_PAYLOAD"/>
  <target action="replace" type="body"/>
</enrich>
```

Comment: Thanks Namal. This is very usefully for my development